# How to resolve this FilerExpression error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I did a gridview with a FilterExpression to filter the content of my gridview.
To filter this one, I use multiple DropDownList. So for my first 3 dropdownlist work fine but the rest of my DropDownList don't work and i don't know why...

EDIT : I think this is my SQL FilterExpression which doesn't work but I don't know.

This is my code SQLDatasource & Filter :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connexionBase %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Nom], [Entite], [Origine], [ObjectifStrategique], [Cle], [MAP], [SNS], [Objectif operationnel], [Description activite], [Debut], [Fin], [Livrables] FROM reponse"
                FilterExpression="Nom like '%{0}%' AND Entite like '%{1}%' AND Origine like '%{2}%' AND ObjectifStrategique like '%{3}%' AND Cle like '%{4}%' AND MAP like '%{5}%' AND SNS like '%{6}%'">
                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Nom" ControlID="NomPersonne" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Entite" ControlID="NomEntite" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Origine" ControlID="ContenuOrigine" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="ObjectifStrategique" ControlID="Objectif_strategique"
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Cle" ControlID="Key" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="MAP" ControlID="map1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="SNS" ControlID="sns1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My DropDownList (don't work) :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Objectif_strategique" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceStrategique"
                                DataTextField="contenuObjectif" CssClass="DropDownList" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>



 <asp:DropDownList ID="sns1" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Oui" Value="Oui" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Non" Value="Non" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>


 <asp:DropDownList ID="map1" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Oui" Value="Oui" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Non" Value="Non" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="Key" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Oui</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Non</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Your code is not enough for pointing out where you stuck please point it out

Comment: You think you have a problem in sql filtering that's wrong you already told us that you can see three drops working

Comment: This is not a error, it's just when I choose of value of one DropDownList, my gridView doesn't filter.

Comment: In fact, I resolved the problem. I had forgot the "AutoPostBack="True" in DropDownList...